# Adding backgrounds to a symantic html element distorts its alignment with others

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am new to writing symantic html code. I am using bootstrap. I want to write my html as symantically as possible. But adding background-color to my h2 tag distorts its alignment with the other elements in the page.

Here is my html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <img src="images/slider/img1.jpg" alt="slider image" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <h2>Product One</h2>
        <div class="prod-slider">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <h2>Product Two</h2>
        <div class="prod-slider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My less is

```
.wrapper{
  .container;  //creates a bootstrap container
  .clearfix();
}
.slider-wrapper{
  .make-row();   //creates a bootstrap row
}
.slider-wrapper img{
  .MakeColumn(12, 12, 12, 12);//creates a 12 column width column.Its similar to adding .col-xs-12
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product-wrapper{
  .make-row(); //creates a row
}

.product-wrapper h2{
  .MakeColumn(12, 12, 12, 12);//creates a 12 column width column.Its similar to adding .col-xs-12
  background-color:#cccfff;//any color code
}
```

Everything works fine as it would if I would have used the bootstrap css classes like .container, .row, .col-XX-12.
However adding the background color to the h2 tag miss aligns it with the image above it. I know I can resolve it by adding an empty div tag as the parent to the h2 tag, but I would not like to do it in order to keep my html code as symantic as possible.

Is there a better way to apply the background to the h2 tag keeping it in aligned to the other elements (like the image above).

Just wanted to add that I tried fixing it using the :before pseudo element but failed.

Comment: Bootstrap columns contain a horizontal padding of 15px. This is used as the whitespace or the gutter between the columns content. The background-color also applies to the padding making it appear as if the image is misaligned to the `h2`. Personally I wouldn't bother trying to make your code as` semantic as possible, nor do I think classes such as `product-wrapper` are more semantic than `.row`

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it all with `<div>` is semantically correct: both `div` and `h2` are block elements, so you can do `<div><h2>Your text</h2></div>`.

Bootstrap is applying custom rules to headings, `padding` is one of them. When you have padding and add background to the element than it will also show up on the padded area (as opposted to the case when you would be using `margin`). If you want to avioid it you need to override Bootstraps h2 padding:

```
.product-wrapper h2{
  .MakeColumn(12, 12, 12, 12);//creates a 12 column width column.Its similar to adding .col-xs-12
  background-color:#cccfff;//any color code
  padding: 0; // This should do the trick for you
}
```